# getting unauthorized 401 error in MERN application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, mongodb

I am developing a web app on MERN stack, I have developed the backend API and they are working fine on postman. The problem is when I'm connecting backend with frontend and running the registration form the data is not being posted. Whenever I'm running this it shows unauthorized 401 error. Here's the code I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am following a tutorial in his video it's working properly without any error but mine is not working. What I could figure out from reading the error is that the problem is in fetch API code it shows error at register.js:37 where I'm defining the fetch API properties other than path.

P.S: console was also showing something like waiting for update signal from hrds or something like that.

Here is the error image

[image]

This is my front end code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const Register = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    gender: "",
    address: "",
    phone: "",
    role: "",
  });
  let name, value;
  const handleinputs = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;

    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };
  const postdata = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      username,
      email,
      password,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender,
      address,
      phone,
      role,
    } = user;
    const res = await fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      authorization: "{TOKEN}",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        email,
        password,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        gender,
        address,
        phone,
        role,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    if (
      data.status === 411 ||
      data.status === 422 ||
      data.status === 418 ||
      !data
    ) {
      window.alert("Invalid Registration");
      console.log("Invalid Registration");
    } else {
      window.alert("Successful Registration");
      console.log("Successful Registration");
      // history.push("/login");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <form method="POST" className="container" noValidate>
          <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="inputusername">
                <i className="far fa-user material-icons-name"></i>
                Username
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="inputEmail4"
                placeholder="Username"
                autoComplete="off"
                name="username"
                required
                value={user.username}
                onChange={handleinputs}
              />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="inputemail">
                <i className="fas fa-envelope-open material-icons-name"></i>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="inputPassword4"
                placeholder="Email"
                autoComplete="off"
                name="email"
                required
                value={user.email}
                onChange={handleinputs}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="inputpassword">
              <i className="fas fa-key materials-icon-name"></i>
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputAddress"
              placeholder="Password"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="password"
              required
              value={user.password}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputfname"
              placeholder="Firstname"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="firstname"
              required
              value={user.firstname}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputlname"
              placeholder="Lastname"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="lastname"
              required
              value={user.lastname}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputgen"
              placeholder="Gender"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="gender"
              required
              value={user.gender}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputaddr"
              placeholder="Address"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="address"
              required
              value={user.address}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputph"
              placeholder="Phone"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="phone"
              required
              value={user.phone}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label htmlFor="role">Role</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inputrole"
              placeholder="Role"
              autoComplete="off"
              name="role"
              required
              value={user.role}
              onChange={handleinputs}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className="form-group form-button">
            <input
              type="submit"
              name="register"
              id="signup"
              className="form-submit"
              value="Register"
              onClick={postdata}
            />
          </div>
          <br />
        </form>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

This is my backend API file

```
const express = require("express");
const db = require("../db/conn.js");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jtoken = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../model/userschema");
const serviceprovider = require("../model/serviceprovider");
const availability = require("../model/availabilities");
const unavailability = require("../model/unavailabilities");
const service = require("../model/services");
const review = require("../model/reviews");
const appointment = require("../model/appointments");
const router = express.Router();
let token;
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Homepage");
});
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.role_id == "1") {
    const {
      last_name,
      first_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      role_id,
      gender,
      address,
      phone,
    } = req.body;
    //console.log(name);
    //console.log(email);
    if (
      !username ||
      !email ||
      !password ||
      !last_name ||
      !first_name ||
      !gender ||
      !address ||
      !phone
    )
      return res
        .status(422)
        .json({ error: "email, username or password is missing" });

    try {
      const usercheck = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      const providercheck = await serviceprovider.findOne({ email: email });
      const usernamecheckprov = await serviceprovider.findOne({
        username: username,
      });
      const usernamecheck = await User.findOne({ username: username });
      if (usercheck && providercheck) {
        return res.status(422).json({ Error: "Email already exists" });
      }
      if (usernamecheck && usernamecheckprov) {
        return res.status(422).json({ Error: "Username already exists" });
      }
      if (gender.length > 1 && (gender !== "M" || gender !== "F")) {
        return res.status(411).json({ error: "Gender's should be M or F" });
      }
      const nuser = new User({
        last_name,
        first_name,
        username,
        email,
        password,
        role_id,
        gender,
        address,
        phone,
      });
      const registered = await nuser.save();
      if (registered) {
        return res.status(201).json({ message: username + " user created" });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(418)
          .json({ Error: username + " Something bad happened" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.json({ Error: error });
    }
  } else if (req.body.role_id == "2") {
    const {
      last_name,
      first_name,
      username,
      email,
      password,
      role_id,
      gender,
      address,
      phone,
      hourlyrate,
      age,
      service_name,
    } = req.body;
    //console.log(name);
    //console.log(email);

    try {
      const usercheckuser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      const usercheck = await serviceprovider.findOne({ email: email });
      const usernamecheck = await serviceprovider.findOne({
        username: username,
      });
      const usernamecheckuser = await User.findOne({ username: username });
      if (usercheck && usercheckuser) {
        return res.status(422).json({ Error: "Email already exists" });
      }
      if (usernamecheck && usernamecheckuser) {
        return res.status(422).json({ Error: "Username already exists" });
      }
      if (gender.length > 1) {
        return res.status(411).json({ error: "Gender's should be M or F" });
      }
      const nuser = new serviceprovider({
        last_name,
        first_name,
        username,
        email,
        password,
        role_id,
        gender,
        address,
        phone,
        hourlyrate,
        age,
        service_name,
      });
      const registered = await nuser.save();
      if (registered) {
        return res
          .status(201)
          .json({ message: username + " service provider created" });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(418)
          .json({ Error: username + " Something bad happened" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.json({ Error: error });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ Error: "Invalid rights" });
  }
  /*
  user
    .findOne({ email: email })
    .then((userexists) => {
      if (userexists)
        return res.status(422).json({ Error: "Email already exists" });
      const nuser = new User({ username, email, password });
      nuser
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          res.status(201).json({ Message: "user created" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).json({ Error: "failed to insert" });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });*/
});
router.get("/customers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "not able to get data" });
  }
});
router.get("/serviceprovider", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await serviceprovider.find({});
    res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "not able to get data" });
  }
});

router.get("/userdetails", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.findOne(req.params.email);
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ Error: "User not found" });
  }
});
router.get("/providerdetails", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await serviceprovider.findOne(req.params.email);
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ Error: "User not found" });
  }
});
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      Error: "invalid credentials",
    });
  }
  try {
    const userdoc = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    const servicedoc = await serviceprovider.findOne({ email: email });
    if (userdoc) {
      const passcheck = await bcrypt.compare(password, userdoc.password);
      token = await userdoc.generateAuthToken();
      res.cookie("jwttoken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      if (!passcheck) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: "Invalid credential",
        });
      } else
        res.status(200).json({
          Message: "login successful",
        });
    } else if (servicedoc) {
      const passcheck = await bcrypt.compare(password, servicedoc.password);
      token = await servicedoc.generateAuthToken();
      res.cookie("jwttoken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      if (!passcheck) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: "Invalid credential",
        });
      } else
        res.status(200).json({
          Message: "login successful",
        });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "Invalid credential",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ Error: "Error occurred" });
  }
});
router.get("/availabilitiesemail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultdoc = await availability.find({
      provider_email: req.params.provider_email,
    });
    if (resultdoc) res.status(200).send(resultdoc);
    else
      res
        .status(404)
        .json({ error: "provider has not created any availabilities" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ Error: "some error occured" });
  }
});
router.get("/availabilities", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultdoc = await availability.find({});
    if (resultdoc) res.status(200).send(resultdoc);
    else res.status(404).json({ error: "Table is empty" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ Error: "some error occured" });
  }
});
router.get("/reviews", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.role_id == "3") {
    try {
      const resultdoc = await review.find({});
      if (resultdoc) res.status(200).send(resultdoc);
      else res.status(404).json({ error: "Table is empty" });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ Error: "some error occured" });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "unauthorized access" });
  }
});
router.get("/reviewsemail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resultdoc = await review.find({ provider_email: req.params.email });
    if (resultdoc) return res.status(200).send(resultdoc);
    else return res.status(404).json({ error: "Table is empty" });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ Error: "some error occured" });
  }
});
router.get("/appointmentemail", async (req, res) => {
  const emails = req.params.email;
  try {
    const usercheck = await User.findOne({ email: emails });
    const provcheck = await serviceprovider.findOne({ email: emails });
    if (usercheck) {
      const result = await appointment.find({ user_email: emails });
      return res.status(200).send(result);
    } else if (provcheck) {
      const result1 = await appointment.find({ provider_email: emails });
      return res.status(200).send(result1);
    } else {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ error: "appointment not found for this email" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ Error: err });
  }
});
router.get("/getappointments", async (req, res) => {
  const emails = req.params.email;
  try {
    const usercheck = await User.findOne({ email: emails });
    const provcheck = await serviceprovider.findOne({ email: emails });
    if (usercheck) {
      const result = await appointment.find({});
      return res.status(200).send(result);
    } 
     else {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ error: "appointment table is empty" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ Error: err });
  }
});


router.post("/requestappointment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      service_names,
      user_email,
      provider_email,
      user_status,
      date,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      instruction,
    } = req.body;
    const providerdoc = await serviceprovider.findOne({
      email: provider_email,
      service_name: service_names,
    });
    const dates = new Date(date);
    console.log(dates);
    const userdoc = await User.findOne({ email: user_email });
    const rate = providerdoc.hourlyrate;
    if (providerdoc && userdoc && user_status == "book") {
      const appoint = new appointment({
        provider_email,
        user_email,
        date,
        start_time,
        end_time,
        rate,
        instruction,
      });
      const appointed = await appoint.save();
      if (appointed) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "appointment created" });
      } else return res.status(500).json({ Error: "Internal Error" });
    } else res.status(404).json({ error: "The Service You want is not here" });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ Error: "some error occured" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my model code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return re.test(email)
};
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim:true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: "Email address is required",
    validate: [validateEmail, "Please fill a valid email address"],
    match: [
      /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
      "Please fill a valid email address",
    ],
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
       
      },
    },
  ],
  role_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
    required: true,
  },
  address:
  {
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    lowercase:true,
  },
  phone:
  {
    type:String,
    required:true
  }
});
userschema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  }
  next();
});
userschema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    let tokengen = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.SECRETKEY);
    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({ token: tokengen });
    await this.save();
    return tokengen;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
const User = mongoose.model("USER", userschema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Where is `{TOKEN}` defined, what is its content? What exactly does your console show? Which tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSmp7Cv-c_0&list=PLwGdqUZWnOp3t3qT7pvAznwUDzKbhEcCc
this is the tutorial link in this he did not specify token in this file here is the link in which he is connecting the backend to frontend
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kvb0cHWFkdc&list=PLwGdqUZWnOp3t3qT7pvAznwUDzKbhEcCc&index=31
I have also added the backend API code with the question

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are passing {TOKEN} as a string to Authorization you should  use backtick(`) instead of double quotes("), if you are defining TOKEN properly then pass it as `` {Authorization: `{TOKEN}`} ``. Also on a side note you should use a Bearer token as it is a better practice but then you have to parse the actual token in the backend.

```
{Authorization: `Bearer {TOKEN}`}
```

Comment: No change still getting this error

Comment: First of all where are you generating the token in your route i.e. the custom method you are defining in your User model generateAuthToken, secondly where are you passing the token in client side the TOKEN variable, usually you have to store the token on client side when you login either in localstorage or cookies, you never store a jwt token in the database.

Comment: this is basically my signup do i need a token for this ? as token would be generated once user is logged in right?

Comment: Then there is no need for you to put an authorization header while fetching a post request from your Register component. Also in your backend /register route look at the top most if else, in the else condition you are responding with a 401 status which is a status code for unauthorised, and that is firing because of your naming from frontend the data you are passing have names with no underscore separation but in backend you are getting the values from the body by underscore naming make sure it is same

Comment: thanks lad i did the same thing with enabling cors it worked